# Array merge combination with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, preg-grep

What array management operations are needed?
So, there are two arrays and I want to combine the following way:

$arr

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-08-16 22:12:04
    [1] => 2015-08-16 13:20:17
    [2] => 2015-08-16 11:45:47
    [3] => 2015-08-16 02:35:12
    [4] => 2015-08-15 19:05:02
    [5] => 2015-08-15 17:35:12
    [6] => 2015-08-15 09:02:25
    [7] => 2015-08-15 07:12:00
    [8] => 2015-08-14 22:12:04
    [9] => 2015-08-14 13:20:17
    [10] => 2015-08-14 11:45:47
)
```

other array ($arr2)

```
Array
(
    [2015-08-16 22:12:04] => 4.8
    [2015-08-16 13:20:17] => 5.8
    [2015-08-16 11:45:47] => 4.7
    [2015-08-16 02:35:12] => 2.8
    [2015-08-15 19:05:02] => 5.0
    [2015-08-15 17:35:12] => 3.0
    [2015-08-15 09:02:25] => 5.6
    [2015-08-15 07:12:00] => 4.0
    [2015-08-14 22:12:04] => 4.8
    [2015-08-14 13:20:17] => 5.8
)
```

I would like the following output:
$arr3

```
Array
(
    2015-08-16 => Array 
        (
           [2015-08-16 22:12:04] => 4.8
           [2015-08-16 13:20:17] => 5.8
           [2015-08-16 11:45:47] => 4.7
           [2015-08-16 02:35:12] => 2.8
        )
    2015-08-15 => Array 
        (
           [2015-08-15 19:05:02] => 5.0
           [2015-08-15 17:35:12] => 3.0
           [2015-08-15 09:02:25] => 5.6
           [2015-08-15 07:12:00] => 4.0
        )
    2015-08-14 => Array 
        (
           [2015-08-14 22:12:04] => 4.8
           [2015-08-14 13:20:17] => 5.8
           [2015-08-14 11:45:26] => 4.4
        )

)
```

So far I got:
(the whole is a for loop)

```
$ts = strtotime($year.'W'.$week.$i);
$thedates = date("Y-m-d", $ts);

$input = preg_quote($thedates, '~');
$input = str_replace("\-","-",$input);
$result = preg_grep('~' . $input . '~', $arr);

$a = array(
   $thedates=>$result,                      
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1439510400] => Array
        (
            [8] => 2015-08-14 22:12:04
            [9] => 2015-08-14 13:20:17
            [10] => 2015-08-14 11:45:47
            [11] => 2015-08-14 02:35:12
        )
)

Array
(
    [1439596800] => Array
        (
            [4] => 2015-08-15 19:05:02
            [5] => 2015-08-15 17:35:12
            [6] => 2015-08-15 09:02:25
            [7] => 2015-08-15 07:12:00
        )
)

Array
(
    [1439683200] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-08-16 22:12:04
            [1] => 2015-08-16 13:20:17
            [2] => 2015-08-16 11:45:47
            [3] => 2015-08-16 02:35:12
        )
)
```

Comment: For what do you need your first array?

Comment: the first array of a previous version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple foreach loop will do what you want. Just `explode()` the key by the space, so you have date and time separated, e.g.

```
<?php

    $result = [];

    foreach($arr2 as $k => $v){
        list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $k);
        $result[$date][$k] = $v;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I think `$result[$date][$time] = $v;` should be `$result[$date][$k] = $v;` because @Stanley wants to have date and time as array key in the second level?

Comment: Perfect! I was too complicated :)

Comment: That works perfect if the first array don't needed. Vote UP! But if author wants combine arrays based on some specific values you need add additional loop that should wrap arr2. It might be needed if arr contains not all dates that are in arr2, but result should be based on arr dates.

Comment: @YuriyNedostup See the comments under OP's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496716/array-merge-combination-with-foreach#comment52853902_32496716

Comment: @Rizier123 ahhh, ok. Sorry. Then I'll take my words back